# ReactJS rendering with a combination of useEffect and state updates

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I am working on a personal project where I have a parent component, `<PageName />`, that contains a child element, `<GlitchingComponent />`. The `<GlitchingComponent />` receives the prop `children` that dictates the information to be generated within the component. So, within `PageName.js`, I simply return `<GlitchingComponent children={"The body content of this page"} />`. When `GlitchingComponent` receives this property, it does the following:

1. Generates a random number between 10 and 36
2. Converts the random number to a string with base 36
3. Returns a substring of one letter
4. Generates a regular expression out of that one letter
5. Iterates over every element of the `children` prop and runs `regexp.test()` on the element
6. If it returns `true`, the element is replaced with a `<span>` that has certain classes applied to it for styling later. Otherwise it simply returns the element

These steps should run on component mount ONLY, so the body content never regenerates. I've done the following with the `useEffect()` hook to achieve this behavior:

```js
React.useEffect(
    () => {
      //content is a state variable of GlitchingComponent
      setContent(generateNewBody());
    },
    []
  );
```

However, part of the styling that is targeted by the classes within the `<span>`s is dependent on the component's state. For that reason, I need the content to re-render WITHOUT calling `generateNewBody()` again, as that causes the random number generation to be executed on every state update, breaking the animation. The current iteration of my code is as follows:

```js
//GlitchingComponent.js
import * as React from "react";

export function GlitchingComponent({ children }) {
  const [glitching, setGlitching] = React.useState(0),
    [triggerState, setTriggerState] = React.useState(0),
    [content, setContent] = React.useState(null);

  const generateApplicationChars = (characters = 2) => {
    let output = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < characters; i++) {
      output.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (36 - 10) + 10).toString(36));
    }
    return output;
  };

//Steps 1-6 outlined above
  const generateNewBody = () => {
    const mainContent = children;
    const mainContentArray = mainContent.split(" ");
    const regExps = generateApplicationChars(3).map((e) => {
      return new RegExp(e, "i");
    });
    const newBody = mainContentArray.map((e) => {
      if (regExps.some((rexp) => rexp.test(e))) {
        return (
          <span
            className={`toGlitch${
              glitching == 0 ? "" : " glitching-" + glitching
            }`}
          >
            {e + " "}
          </span>
        );
      } else {
        return e + " ";
      }
    });
    return newBody;
  };

//The state update that controls the styles
  const glitchController = () => {
    setTriggerState(triggerState + 1);
    setGlitching(1);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setTriggerState(triggerState + 1);
      setGlitching(0);
    }, 133);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setTriggerState(triggerState + 1);
      setGlitching(1);
    }, 220);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setTriggerState(triggerState + 1);
      setGlitching(2);
    }, 350);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setTriggerState(triggerState + 1);
      setGlitching(3);
    }, 600);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setTriggerState(triggerState + 1);
      setGlitching(0);
    }, 750);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setTriggerState(triggerState + 1);
      setGlitching(3);
    }, 800);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setGlitching(0);
      setTriggerState(0);
    }, 1000);
  };

//The useEffect hook to generate the new content on component mount
  React.useEffect(
    () => {
      setContent(generateNewBody());
    },
    []
  );
//An attempt to call glitchController() on triggerState update
  React.useEffect(() => {
    glitchController();
  }, [triggerState]);

  return (
    <div
      className="content"
      onClick={() => {
        setTriggerState(triggerState + 1); //triggerState update
      }}
    >
      {content}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've confirmed that `generateNewBody()`, `generateApplicationCharacters()`, and `glitchHandler()` behave as I expect/want them to. However, with the current iteration of the code, it doesn't seem as though the second `useEffect()` hook is being called to apply the styles.

I've tried pulling the functions outside of the component definition, as well as only using one `useEffect()` hook. I've also tried different variations of the `triggerState` state variable, but the currently implemented one is as close to my conceptual understanding of what I am expecting to happen as anything else I've seen.

Do I have an improper understanding of `useEffect()`, state changes, or rendering concepts? Is there somewhere I can read more about this? What should I do to achieve the effect I'm looking for?